# Old `npm start` script being ran by Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Despite re-deploying and even disabling/re-enabling the application Google App Engine keeps trying to run the `npm start` script from an old version of the app. I noticed this because it used to try to run a migration script, then start the server. Now the migration script errors, which is what got my attention.

I've since tried to also update the version number in the `package.json` since the logs that are failing specified it was trying to run `version 1.0.0` of my app. So I figured maybe I need to bump the version.

Despite that, the log that errors still says `PROJECT_NAME@1.0.0 start: npm run migrate && node src/server.js` which is clearly the old one.

I started a project on Node.js Flexible environment for Google App Engine, then switched to Standard environment (which was released shortly after I started the project). I'm speculating that perhaps it's trying to run flexible environment script too? But, I don't know how to make it stop.

Oh, one more important detail: The app *is running* and working despite supposedly erroring on startup. So it definitely seems like it's trying to run both versions and only one is succeeding.

Comment: Can you also share your app.yaml (removing sensitive part of course). And can you confirm that the logs you are seeing are produced by your new version (by filtering logs by version)

Comment: Hey! Just now got a chance to look at this issue again. I tried what you suggested on Twitter: twitter.com/steren/status/1042987724918026240. I was all excited at first because I didn't see it for a a few minutes, but then it happened again.

My app.yaml is very simple for this: https://gist.github.com/HenrikJoreteg/6149f1bd3911388f293b1d0781baee16

Comment: I'm probably just missing it, but I don't see an obvious way to filter logs by app version. How do I do this?

Comment: I figured out how to do it... yes, they're being produced in the latest version.

Comment: Can you deploy the same app to a different service? (add `service: foo` to your app.yaml) and let me know if you still see the issue?

Comment: Similarly, can you deploy it to a new project? and let me know if you see the issue.

Comment: Also, on GAE Standard, you can remove the `inbound_services` and `beta_settings. cloud_sql_instances` attributes, these are not used by the standard environment

Comment: @Steren hey! So due to my ignorance of how App Engine works, I incorrectly attributed the newer logs (showing the errors) to my new version. As it turns out, they were being caused by an old instance from JUNE! Given that I deployed a new "default" service I assumed all previous ones would be stopped. But there was one instance that still said "serving" and "environment: flexible". I stopped that (using the console) and now the problem is gone. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there was an old instance running in the "flexible" environment.

Deploying a new "default" service running in "standard" environment does not seem to stop other deployed versions in the "flexible" environment.

The fix involved opening Google's Cloud Console for App Engine, clicking "versions" and finding/stopping/deleting the old versions from "flexible" environment.

Huge thanks to @Steren for helping me figure out what was going on.